# GCP, Common labels for all project resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Google Cloud recently released labels feature (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources). Looks very handy. Is it possible to label all project resources with some 'common' labels which can be redefined on resource level?

Example: 
All project resources obtain label *state:inuse*, but for exact disk we can update in to *state:readyfordeletion*

**UPDATE**
It may looks like labels inheritance/override:

projectA (state:inuse)
- instance-1 (state:inuse, inherited)
- instance-2 (state:inuse, inherited)
- instance-3 (state:readyfordeletion, overridden)

In this case, you can define top-level (project-level) labels which will be inherited by all project resources. And then on exact resource you'll be able to re-define same label with non-default value

Comment: Its not possible to add the label to the resource with same key. For example you cannot have state:inuse and state:readyfordeletion applied to the same disk.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the documentation [Creating and managing labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels):

> A label is a key-value pair that helps you organize your Google Cloud instances. You can attach a label to each resource, then filter the resources based on their labels. Information about labels is forwarded to the billing system, so you can break down your billing charges by label.

and

> Here are some common use cases for labels:
>
> - Team or cost center labels: Add labels based on team or cost center to distinguish instances owned by different teams (for example, `team:research` and `team:analytics`). You can use this type of label for cost accounting or budgeting.
> - Component labels: For example, `component:redis`, `component:frontend`, `component:ingest`, and `component:dashboard`.
> - Environment or stage labels: For example, environment:production and environment:test.
> - State labels: For example, `state:active`, `state:readytodelete`, and `state:archive`.
> - Virtual machine labels: A label can be attached to a virtual machine. Virtual machine tags that you defined in the past will appear as a label without a value.

> Is it possible to label all project resources with some 'common' labels which can be redefined on resource level?

**You can set labels on the resources** when you create them or you can add labels to already created resources. Unfortunately **you're not able to label all GCP resources**. You can find more details in the documentation [Creating and managing labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels), section [Services currently supporting labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#label_support). You can use API calls, `gcloud` commands and the Console to set/change/remove labels from any resources that support it.

> It may looks like labels inheritance/override

**Unfortunately there's no "inheritance/override"**, but you can have a few labels for one resource. For example for a GCP VM:

```
gcloud compute instances add-labels example-instance  --labels = label0 = value0, label2 = value1
```

Please have a look at the documentation [Labeling resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) to find more details about labeling GCE resources.

I hope it was helpful.